# Initialization of NSAttributedString is crashing application

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, crashlytics

Below code is crashing(not always but rarely) despite the fact that it is inside `do-catch` block.
`Fabric crashlytics` states that exception is `Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException` and sometimes this `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016fccb1f8`

```
do {
    return try NSAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [
            .documentType:  NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ],
        documentAttributes: nil
    )
} catch {
    return NSAttributedString()
}
```

While I read apple docs of `NSAttributedString` it states that it should be on main thread so I surround it with `Dispatch.main.async` block but doing this is not setting the styles that are set on `NSAttributedString`

Comment: Can it be that your data is incorrect?

Comment: That seems not possible as I can't replicate that issue and according to app center from thousands of users only 58 users are getting these crashes.

Answer (score 10):

As per the resolution provided by apple developer forum here : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115405

> Sadly, this is a known bug in iOS (r. 23592459) that can potentially
>   affect anyone who constructs an NSAttributedString from HTML.
>
> There isn’t a good workaround for this other than to avoid this API
>   altogether.  My advice:
>
> If you’re displaying large chunks of complex HTML, use a WKWebView.
>
> If this HTML is highly constrained — perhaps you’re just using HTML as
>   an easy way to transfer a constrained set of attributes, like bold and
>   italics — create your own markup system that doesn’t relying on HTML. 
>   Or parse the HTML for just these attributes and use the result to
>   create your attributed string.
>
> I’m sorry I don’t have better news here.

So, to avoid the crash, you might need to avoid using ***NSAttributedString(
        data:*** function itself and write your own way to parse the html.

Answer (score 4):

Update the UI only in Main Thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    textLabel.attributedText = generateAttribString()
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but doing this is not setting styles that are provided in nsattributedstring, just setting the text.

Comment: I think I'll apply this and deploy then notice it these crashes gone or not.

Comment: @Yawar Is the Crash fixed ? Can you confirm is this working fine in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert HTML to String, you can use the extension on String as below:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: doing exactly same and it is running perfect but crashing sometimes on some devies.

Comment: maybe the reason is your data is not correct. There is nothing else which can cause crash in this code.

Comment: incase data is wrong, it should be cater in `catch` block

Comment: In my case it won't because "Data(utf8)" may cause crash if String is not converted into Data and it will not go in catch block.

Comment: data is initialized like this `guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }`

Comment: Oh yes! Then you are right. but then there should be no scope of crash. Are you sure that crash is happening at this line because it may be a random crash

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Any success?